# cannot get access to the HDD after LVM

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lvm

I have two drives: disk 1(sdb) - ssd 256 gb, disk 2 (sda) - hdd 1tb.

Firstly I had windows10 installed on the disk1 (sdb) and  then  I installed kubuntu on disk2 (rather part of disk2 (sda), because to the other part I had access from both OS).

Few days ago I decided to remove windows and install kubuntu on disk1(sdb), during instalation I selected: Guided - use entire disk and set up LVM. After that I fully lost access to the disk2(sda).

How can I solve it (got access and don`t lose previous files) 
I am not advanced user, so ask about any necessary details

Gparted results:

Disk 2(sda)

[image]

Disk 1 (sdb)

[image]

Comment: run this `sudo apt install gparted && sudo gparted` take a screen screnshot of what shows up for both drives: you can select drives with the top rightmost dropdown menu.

Comment: @tatsu, added it to the description

Comment: good feedback but the way you labeled you images makes me unsure which one you currently are using successfully and are booting on out of the two disks. could you call them "sda" and "sdb" instead please. I'm pretty much have yourr solution: you can create a new partition table from gparted (preferebly without LVM) but I'm not sure which disk to that on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looking good.

If you have nothing to recover from disk 2 (sda, for some reason) and if we are in agreement that that is not the disk you are booting from nor the one which your currently working system is installed to...

then

you can format it using gparted :

select "Partition" -> "New Partition Table..." :
[image]

after that click apply

let it finish

and after that you can right click on the empty space and partition it to what you want (I prefer ext4).

Once you're done you may use disks to make this drive mount on boot : [Hardware drives Hide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128813/hardware-drives-hide/1128835#1128835)

if you do not mind the hassle (and if the install is fairly recent, meaning you stand to loose little from formatting everything), then in the spirit of making things pitch perfect, you can format the drive you are not booted to and redo the install process.

Comment: Actually the main problem, that I need the data from disk2(sda)

Comment: and you can't read sda?

Comment: yes exactly. I tried to mount it somewhere, but it still does not help. Mounted folder contains only folder "lost + found" and it is empty. However, Gparted says that size of disk is over 900GB

Comment: ok this is a case of data recovery. I recommend you use TestDisk to restore the partition that was previously there. with a scan it'll present you with a historic of the partition setups that used to be in place there. you can select the one just before current state and restore it. after reboot it should read as it was before the format. `sudo apt-get install -y testdisk && sudo testdisk` https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Log_creation if you feel data recovery is beyond your skill you may need to contact a professional for this.