# Hardware drives Hide

Tags: 18.04, drive

When I restart pc hardware drives hide. Can you help me, please?

Here is a very short screen recording to explain the problem. [Download](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8355914126/Drive_bug.mkv.html)

Thanks

Comment: I clicked on your link, but nothing helpful... Could you please check on it? Is it a valid one?

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider you may need to allow Google to translate the page after which you'll see a link in English to download the video.

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider excuse me that site wasn't English, but download click is that orange red key that  is middle and left in monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the steps to solve your isue :

open up "drives" from the start menu, once opened the app looks like this (my system is in French) :

[image: drives]

you can go to the gear wheels of the drive you want mounted every boot and from that menu select "Modify Mount Options"

[image: mount options]

and select "mount at startup" :

[image: mount at startup]